# Pinescript - Alert when two lines meet

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have the problem that I want to trigger an alert on an indicator when two lines meet on a candlestick. I work in the script with real-time candles, so it is possible to execute this state. Unfortunately, the old one is executed one candle later and in some cases leads to wrong trades. Is it possible to execute the alert exactly on the candle in the script below? I tried it several times and didn't get it.

[Screen Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGQ7A.jpg)

```
//@version=5
strategy("Test 37", process_orders_on_close=true, max_bars_back = 4000, overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, calc_on_every_tick=true)

tick = syminfo.ticker

ZZPercent = input.float(0.45, title="Minimum % Change")

trend = 0
trend := na(trend[1]) ? 1 : trend[1]
LL = 0.0
LL := na(LL[1]) ? low : LL[1]
HH = 0.0
HH := na(HH[1]) ? high : HH[1]

PivotChg = ZZPercent * 0.01
float zigzag = na

if (trend > 0)       // trend is up, look for new swing low
    if (high >= HH)  // new higher high detected
        HH := high
        //label.new(bar_index, na, "", color=color.rgb(233, 7, 7), textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
    else
        if (low < HH * (1 - PivotChg))
            zigzag := high[1]
            trend := -1
            LL := low

        // Short- Auslöser 
        if (low < HH * (1 - PivotChg))
            label.new(bar_index, na, "", color=color.rgb(240, 53, 6), textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
            alert("SS_Alert Short " + str.tostring(tick), alert.freq_once_per_bar)  // , freq = alert.freq_all   alert.freq_once_per_bar


else                 // trend is down, look for new swing high
    if (low <= LL)   // new lower low detected
        LL := low
        //label.new(bar_index, na, "", color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
    else
        if (high > LL * (1 + PivotChg))
            zigzag := low[1]
            trend := 1
            HH := high

        // Long- Auslöser 
        if (high > LL * (1 + PivotChg))
            label.new(bar_index, na, "", color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
            alert("LL_Alert Long " + str.tostring(tick), alert.freq_once_per_bar)  // , freq = alert.freq_all   alert.freq_once_per_bar


plot(series=zigzag, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, offset=-1)
```